# Magento 2: How to move recently viewed

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

Having problems working out how to move the recently viewed block. I want it to sit above the details/review tabs but can't work out how to move it in the xml?

Comment: what u mean by `Recently moved block`?

Comment: Edited meant recently viewed!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<move element="recently_viewed" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.details"/>
```